# Paying taxes as foreigner for working as freelancer for US company

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, germany, foreign-income

I am a german citizen and live in Germany, and  want to work as a freelance-translator for a company called "gengo" , that seems to be registered in the US (quoting from the website: "a Delaware corporation"). They classify the translators as "independent contractors" (see https://gengo.com/legal/translator-agreement/). In the same document, they say  I "agree to sign US tax and regulatory documentation".
I am pretty sure that I have to pay taxes in Germany, but does that mean that I also have to pay taxes in the US?